# How can I obtain access to a networked location?

Tags: windows, networking, rust

My program, when started up with the system, is unable to access a networked location:

```
fn main() {
    ensure_network("\\\\SERVER\\".to_string());
}

fn ensure_network(network_dir: String) {
    let timer = std::time::Instant::now();
    let mut prev_counter = 0;
    loop {
        if std::fs::read_dir(&network_dir).is_ok() {
            break;
        }
        if timer.elapsed().as_secs() > prev_counter + 60 {
            println!("Still Failing.");
            prev_counter = timer.elapsed().as_secs();
        }
        std::hint::spin_loop();
    }
    println!("Network access obtained (Time elapsed: {})",
        timer.elapsed().as_secs_f32());
}
```

**Edit (Restating problem after much research into the issue):**

This program starts up with the PC using Task Scheduler. It is set to "Run only when user is logged on" and to "Run with highest privileges." However, most of the time the program fails to find the connection and gives the error, `"The user name or password is incorrect. (os error 1326)."`

- The program succeeds when run manually with administrator privilege.
- On occasion the program will succeed on startup, but this is rare.
- The program will succeed if *any* other application is started `as administrator` after the program enters its loop.

Comment: What happens if you launch the second instance _without_ accessing the network share before?

Comment: I tested this right now and the second instance worked while the first continued to fail.

Comment: There was a similar issue (which was fixed in glibc too): https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41570 may be you could take a look see if this issue is related somehow

Comment: @stepan That is eerily similar. However, I have added some odd information to my `edit 2` above. And it seems deeper than rust simply failing to connect. It works when it's not admin and it works when admin is granted to any external application at all. (See edit)

Comment: @VCD_WL What OS are you running this code on?

Comment: @Ricardo Windows.

Comment: If the scheduled task is set to "Run whether user is logged on or not" and "Do not store password. The task will only have access to local resources" is checked, then the task will not have the necessary credentials to establish the shared folder connection itself. Is your scheduled task configured this way?

Comment: @FrancisGagné The task is setup for `Run with highest privileges` and `Run only when the user is logged on`.

Comment: Have you tried looking at *what* error you are getting?

Comment: Something else to try would be replacing `std::fs::read_dir(...)` with `std::path::Path::new(...).exists()`.

Comment: @user3840170 The error I receive is: `The user name or password is incorrect. (os error 1326) ` The odd thing is the fix to this problem is starting *ANY* application as administrator. For example, after running this program, if it's failing, I can start Notepad.exe as administrator and the program will begin to work.

Comment: @silvergasp I have tried this, but it doesn't make any difference to the functionality.

Comment: Is the task user  in admin group? Are you trying to access a Windows share folder?

Comment: The user is an admin and the task is run with highest privileges and yes the location is a shared Windows folder. @Jaroost

Comment: @WCD_WL It's looks like purely a Windows issue. Can you run "klist.exe" from your program to see if you have a Kerberos ticket when it doesn't work and when it does? I suspect running another app as administrator makes a ticket is available to your program afterward and makes it working properly.

Comment: Is the user in task scheduler the same as the user that runs it when testing? e.g. SYSTEM is running the task but cool_guy is running the exe manually.

Comment: @BrandonKauffman I have verified that both tasks run under the same local administrator account.

Comment: @BrunoRohée Both before and after the code is working the output is `Cached Tickets: (0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Task Scheduler you can delay the execution of the task.

It's okay if you execute it after login, but when Active Directory or anyway a Domain system is between you and the login, the connection to the shared storage may take a while, and the program may try to execute before this happens. Try to put on a 10-20 seconds delay on it and see if this solve your problem.

If it doesn't work, again supposing that you have a domain in the middle, you may need to explicit give user and passwd to access the network where the directory you're looking for.

Comment: Task Scheduler is set to use a 1-minute delay, so that isn't the issue. I can resolve the connection using net use with username and password, but it seems insecure to add the password into the program in this way. I was really hoping to avoid this. But, after months of having this question open and after two bounties. I will close and accept for now.

Comment: @VCD_WL If you want to make more 'secure' this process you can do some workarounds, these aren't secure ways but surely make this script less insecure. You can create some sort of credentials file and save it into a folder with restricted permissions somewhere. Then you could remove the extension to that file (you can still open it with notepad or other text editor) and so on, you can add 'security' layers by making it harder to find instead of just hardcoding your password.